# Not working stylus heading loop before content

Tags: css, stylus

Working code:

Stylus

```
for num, $s in (1..6)
    h{$s+1}
        display inline-block
```

HTML

```
h1:before {
  position: relative;
}
h2:before {
  position: relative;
}
h3:before {
  position: relative;
}
h4:before {
  position: relative;
}
h5:before {
  position: relative;
}
h6:before {
  position: relative;
}
```

Not working code:

Stylus

```
for num, $s in (1..6)
    h{$s+1}
        &:before
            display inline-block
            content h{$s+1}
```

How would you do to make the resulting code the next and can be displayed in the before content of the css

HTML

```
h1:before {
  content: "h1";
}
h2:before {
  content: "h2";
}
h3:before {
  content: "h3";
}
h4:before {
  content: "h4";
}
h5:before {
  content: "h5";
}
h6:before {
  content: "h6";
}
```

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work code:

Stylus

```
for $i in (1..6)
    h{$i}
        &:before
            content "h" + $i
```

HTML

```
h1:before {
  content: 'h1';
}
h2:before {
  content: 'h2';
}
h3:before {
  content: 'h3';
}
h4:before {
  content: 'h4';
}
h5:before {
  content: 'h5';
}
h6:before {
  content: 'h6';
}
```